# Video capturing on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, video-capture, v4l2

I have a problem using a web camera (defender c-110) on mk802ii with debian `armhf` from [here](https://www.miniand.com/forums/forums/development/topics/debian-wheezy-lxde-armhf-build):

```
     $ avconv -f video4linux2 -r 5 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 out.avi
     avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
     built on Mar 24 2013 22:04:47 with gcc 4.6.3
     [video4linux2 @ 0x168bc40] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/5 to 1/30
     [video4linux2 @ 0x168bc40] ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON): Message too long
     /dev/video0: Message too long
```

The same error I recieve using [this](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) example. What does this error means and what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used  OTG port.